# MLT compile error on CentOS 6.7

Tags: mlt

Installing on CentOS 6.7

Make install getting this error:

```
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/mlt/src/modules/avformat'
cc -I../.. -DARCH_X86_64 -Wall -DPIC   -O2 -pipe -fno-tree-dominator-opts -fno-tree-pre -ffast-math -DUSE_MMX -DUSE_SSE -DUSE_SSE2 -g -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fPIC -pthread -DAVDATADIR=\"/usr/share/ffmpeg/\" -I/usr/include/ffmpeg   -I/usr/include/ffmpeg   -I/usr/include/ffmpeg   -I/usr/include/ffmpeg   -I/usr/include/ffmpeg   -DFILTERS -DCODECS -DAVDEVICE   -c -o filter_avcolour_space.o filter_avcolour_space.c
filter_avcolour_space.c: In function ‘convert_mlt_to_av_cs’:
filter_avcolour_space.c:50: error: ‘AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24’ undeclared (first use in this function)
filter_avcolour_space.c:50: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
...
filter_avcolour_space.c:323: error: ‘AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[2]: *** [filter_avcolour_space.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: *** [filter_avdeinterlace.o] Error 1
filter_swscale.c: In function ‘filter_swscale_init’:
filter_swscale.c:179: error: ‘AV_PIX_FMT_RGB32’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[2]: *** [filter_swscale.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/mlt/src/modules'
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Used repo:

Download the latest nux-dextop-release rpm from
http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/
Install nux-dextop-release rpm:

## rpm -Uvh nux-dextop-release*rpm

Install mlt rpm package:

## yum install mlt